# Copy an Excel ChartArea with VBA, poor performance

Tags: performance, excel, charts, copy-paste, vba

I want to copy an Excel ChartArea with VBA. This code do the job, but it takes 10 seconds in my computer while copying:

```
Sub copyChart()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Sheets("Gráficas")
    sht.ChartObjects("Gráfico 1").Chart.ChartArea.Copy
End Sub
```

How could I improve the performance?

I did test the following:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

but no way...

Any idea?
I did test that the "CopyPicture" method is almost instantaneous but, I need the ChartArea to be copied.

**EDIT**:
Screenshot of dynamic table:
[image: dynamic table the chart comes from]

Comment: How big is the chart? Where is the Excel file (on a PC, on a shared folder or somewhere else) How old is your PC? Seriously, it should be rather fast.

Comment: The chart comes from a dinamic table with about 20 values. The PC is a new Toshiba laptop with Windows 10. The excel file is in local disc.

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of the table?

Comment: When copying the chart, the Excel process reaches 25% CPU

Comment: Same Excel book (6 MB) supports several hundreds of tables (with his associated charts) like this one. Could the problem be because of that?

Comment: It could be. Create only this table and a chart on an empty book, and try it from there.